# Calculate the vector field given a surface using divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, divergence-theorem

Calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x, y, z) = (y + 2xz, y + z, −2x − z^2)$ through the surface given by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $x, y, z > 0$. The normal direction to the surface points away from the origin.

What I did was I first changed my coordinates and then basically used the divergence theorem  on the $1/8$ of the sphere.
$$\iint F(x,y,z) \cdot ds = \iiint_{k} r^2\sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta = \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

But in the answers this is what they did:
[image]

I understand they added the remaining 2D sides of the open $1/8$ of a sphere but is it really necessary? Doesn't the divergence already take care of that? That brings me to my next question does the divergence actually take care of that since these three surfaces isn't even in integral? Last but not least, how does telling me the that the normal vector points away from the origin help me? Is it just to tell kind of tell us that the surface is oriented?

Comment: Read the theorem very carefully.

Comment: In the divergence theorem, the flux of a vector field should be through a **closed** surface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: @RobertZ yeah you're right for example if I am supposed to calculate the divergence through a hemisphere I'd need to calculate the plane that closes the hemisphere too right?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Yes, here you have an octant of sphere which becomes a closed surface together with the $3$ quarters of disc $A_x$, $A_y$ and $A_z$

Comment: I think I get it now but just to double check here they are asking me about the flux of the open surface right. But when I use the divergence theorem formula, I end up calculating for the closed surface and thus I need to remove 3 of the surface integrals right by calculating the 3 double integrals?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Yes, you have to remove those 3 fluxes